# Using XSLT, how to get an attribute from multiple xml files outputed into one single file?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following situation: out of multiple almost similar in structure xml files, I need to extract an attribute and the file from which it comes from.

I believe I am close to a solution, but cannot make it work. I am new to xml and xslt and would need some guidance. Thank you.

My multiple xml files are all in the same location and they have the following structure:

```html
<erpConnector>
  <sections>
    <section name="Section1">
      <!-- other irrelevant content here -->
    </section>
    <section name="Section2">
      <!-- other irrelevant content here -->
    </section>
    <section name="Section3">
      <!-- other irrelevant content here -->
    </section>
  </sections>
</erpConnector>
```

I created a separate xml file called "report.xml" which acts like an aggregator for all my other xml files. It looks like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="reports3.xsl" version="1.0"?>
<report>
 <title>Section names</title>
 <configfile name="C:\Users\.myFirstXMLfile.xml"/>
 <configfile name="C:\Users\mySecondXMLfile.xml"/>
</report>
```

Lastly, I have the xsl file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
   <head>
    <title><xsl:value-of select="/report/title"/></title>
   </head>
   <body>
    <xsl:for-each select="/report/configfile">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="document(@name)/erpConnector"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </body>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <h1>
   <xsl:value-of select="erpConnector/sections/section/@name"/>
   <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  </h1>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My output is just "<h1> <\h1>" .

Please let me know what could be the cause and how to address it.

The output could look like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Basic HTML Table</h2>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Section name</th>
    <th>Filename</th> 

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Section1</td>
    <td>myfirstxml</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Section2</td>
    <td>mysecondxml</td>

  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

But if any other format is easier to obtain, that would be fine as well.

Thank you!

Comment: You have two templates with the same match pattern. Only the last one of these is being applied. Since your 1st template applies templates to `erpConnector`, that's what your other template should match. -- Note that the template as currently written tries to output the name of the 1st section in the document - which is not what you said you wanted.

Comment: So which output do you want to create exactly? Show to minimal sample input files and the corresponding (HTML?) result you want to create/.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, I am trying to get an output similar to this: a header with just the text "Section names" and then lines with each section name. Ideally, it would have two columns, the additional one containing information about the file from which the section name was extracted.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the exact **code** your example should produce.

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k , thank you very much for your answer. Both outputs you suggested are great and I can use them. However, my file does not get transformed. I do not get any error so I'm not sure what's wrong. I tried in Notepad++, using the "report.xml" file which is in the initial post. If I add the full path to firefox, all it shows is: "Section names". Do you have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: I am afraid not. A browser is not a good testing tool. If you're not seeing the `html` and `body` wrappers, then your `report.xml` is not being transformed. If you do see them, but aren't getting any section data, then you may have the wrong paths.

Comment: I do not see the html and body wrappers, so it is not being transformed I guess. I will try to install something better that might at least give an error and tell me why. Thank you very much for all the help. I will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: It worked with a different xml editor than notepad++ or firefox. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/report">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h1>
                <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
            </h1>
            <xsl:for-each select="configfile">
                <h2>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                </h2>
                <xsl:for-each select="document(@name)/erpConnector/sections/section">
                    <p>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                    </p>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which in your example would produce a result like:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Section names</h1>
    <h2>myFirstXMLfile.xml</h2>
    <p>Section1</p>
    <p>Section2</p>
    <p>Section3</p>
    <h2>mySecondXMLfile.xml</h2>
    <p>Section1b</p>
    <p>Section2b</p>
    <p>Section3b</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

If your prefer to output a table, then try:

```
<xsl:template match="/report">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h1>
                <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
            </h1>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Section name</th>
                    <th>Filename</th> 
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="configfile">
                    <xsl:variable name="filename" select="@name" />
                    <xsl:for-each select="document($filename)/erpConnector/sections/section">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$filename"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>    
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```